# Nextauth.js | Session is null after successfull login and getting 200 status code in response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, next.js, next-auth

Using Nextauth.js along with my Next 14 app with app router I haved faced the issue that my session is always null and status is "unauthenticated" after successfull login with my form.

I have provided the next snippets of my code:

Actions that are being evoked after pressing submit button:

AuthForm.tsx:

```
"use client";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

...


const onSignUpFormSubmit = async (
    values: z.infer<typeof formSignUpSchema>,
  ) => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/sign-up", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ values }),
    });
    const userInfo = await response.json();
    console.log(userInfo);
  };

  const onLogInFormSubmit = async (
    values: z.infer<typeof formLogInSchema>,
    e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>,
  ) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await signIn("credentials", {
      email: values.email,
      password: values.password,
      redirect: false,
    });
    console.log({ response });
  };
```

authOptions.ts:

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";

import prisma from "./db";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma!) as Adapter,
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {},
        password: {},
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials.password) {
          return null;
        }

        console.log(credentials, "credentials");

        const user = await prisma?.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email,
          },
        });

        if (!user) {
          return null;
        }

        const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.password,
        );
        if (!passwordsMatch) {
          return null;
        }
        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
};
```

SessionProvider.tsx (root layout.tsx is wrapped with this):

```
"use client";

import React from "react";

import { SessionProvider, SessionProviderProps } from "next-auth/react";

export default function AuthSessionProvider({
  children,
  session,
}: SessionProviderProps) {
  return <SessionProvider session={session}>{children}</SessionProvider>;
}
```

page.tsx (when I am trying to access session):

**session is null, and status is unauthenticated**

```
"use client";

import React from "react";

import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const SomePage = () => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  console.log(session, status);

  return <p>hello {session?.user?.email}</p>;
};

export default SomePage;
```

Network section in devtools after log in:
[dev tools network section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnAFp.png)

User that returning after log in:

[user returned from db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKmsM.png)

Dont really see what could be wrong here.